# ld path update for compiling

Tags: c++, linux, path, compilation

I just installed manually **apr** and **apr_util** so i can install **activemq c++** library.

When i try to **make** the cpp library i get the following error:

**

libtool: link: g++ -ansi -pedantic -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1 -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1 -I/usr/kerberos/include -W -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -fPIC -fstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Wno-long-long -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1 -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1 -I/usr/kerberos/include -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-uninitialized -I./../main -g -O2 -pthread -o .libs/example example-main.o  ../main/.libs/libactivemq-cpp.so -lexpat -L/usr/kerberos/lib64 /usr/local/apr/lib/libaprutil-1.so /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.so -luuid -lrt -lcrypt /usr/local/apr/lib/libexpat.so -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lz -lpthread -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/apr/lib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpat
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

**

and **expat** is within **apr-util** and not being linked. how can i update the ld path so that make or environment will find it?

or in short: how can i resolve this?

Comment: `ld` has nothing to do with compiling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you'll need to manually specify the library path using `-L` option.

It would look like `ld filename -Lpath -llibname` in a single `ld` operation. Or in this case you may need to add the paths of your library(apr-util here) to the constant of library paths in a `Makefile`.

Comment: Usually the library is already in the proper place and you don't need to specify anything at all.

Comment: @DarthVader Seems you should install `expat` first. Get it from your package manager or http://sourceforge.net/projects/expat/

Comment: Package expat-1.95.8-8.3.el5_5.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package expat-1.95.8-8.3.el5_5.3.i386 already installed and latest version

Comment: @DarthVader oops. Then fedora may have the expat package separated into a runtime one and a development one. Things are similar on ubuntu when i tried to develop with OpenIL. But since I'm using ArchLinux now and when searching for expat i got only one resulting package, I didn't considered about this "separating package strategy" :-(